# What do the words 「しとられん」, 「ちゅうて」 and 「おびえとるん」 mean?

Tags: words, manga

I have found them in a manga. It is a dialogue discussing to the third person going into a Pachinko shop.

Here is the full sentence

> なんせ ここいらの商人【しょうにん】どもは あのジョーがくると おちおち商売【しょうばい】**しとられん ちゅうて おびえとるん** じゃから

What do the words しとられん, ちゅうて and おびえとるん mean?

Comment: What manga/chapter? Providing more context might help.

Comment: @Eric It came from Ashita no Joe, vol.1, first panel of the page 104.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

しとられん means you can't do something or can't focus on something, because there is something more important. In this sentence, it says when ジョー comes, you can't do businesses anymore. Probably, ジョー is a person who interrupt the businesses.

~ ちゅうて means "(someone) says ~". ちゅうて comes right after the content of what they speak. In this context, 商人 said "あのジョーがくるとおちおち商売しとられん".

おびえとる mean fear/be afraid of. In this context,　商人 is afraid of ジョー.

By the way, they all are dialect spoken by west part of Japanese people. In standard Japanese しとられん is equivalent to してられない, ちゅうて is equivalent to と言って, おびえとるん is equivalent to おびえている.

Comment: Just some nitpicks. しとられん→しておられん→しておられぬ→して**い**られない, ちゅうて→とゆうて→と言うて→と言って, おびえとるん→おびえておるん→おびえている**の**.